# Is it safe to uninstall the Application Insights nuget packages?

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a UWP app. It has three Application Insights NuGet packages.

Do they serve some purpose by themselves, or are they there so that we can reference them in code and therefore since I'm not doing that, can I uninstall those NuGet packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uninstall Application Insights from your UWP app safely. App Insights for mobile apps were supported before version 2.0.0. In this version support for mobile apps was deprecated and developers should now use the new [Visual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) instead, which has more services directly targeting mobile apps.